# How Exactly Does the int() function work?

Tags: python

This is python 3. I have come upon some strange error where it says:
'can't assign to operator'. Please help with this and any other errors you may find. Thanks

```
Answer = 0
def Game():
    print('Hello! Enter in a number to multiply!')
    Input1 = input
    print('Ok, now enter another number to multiply!')
    Input2 = input
    print('Now let me think about that.....')
    int(Input1) * int(Input2) = Answer
    print('The answer to that is' + Answer + '!')

playAgain = 'yes'
while playAgain == 'yes':
    Game()
    print('Do you want to play again? (Yes or No?)')
    playAgain = input()
```

Comment: It's not a function, it's a class. Anyways, your left hand side and your right hand side are flipped.

Comment: `int(Input1) * int(Input2) = Answer` is like `2 * 2 = Answer`.

Comment: Ummm. sorry but im new to this

Comment: what is a class

Comment: The assignment target has to be on the left hand side. `*` is an operator and with `int(Input1) * int(Input2) = Answer` you are trying to assign the value of `Answer` to the `*` operation. That's that the error says.

Comment: Can u plz rewrite my code and post it so that i can see the right code

Comment: Look at the other cases where you are using the assignment operator (correctly). You are using `Answer = 0` and `playAgain = 'yes'`. Can you see that those are different than `int(Input1) * int(Input2) = Answer` ?

Comment: Yes, but now that I run it, it says this:

Comment: TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're confused about how assignments work. When you want to assign to a variable, the variable always goes on the left. So to set `Answer`, it should be:

```
Answer = ...
```

not

```
... = Answer
```

You shouldn't think of this as just a statement that two things are conceptually equal, assignment is an action and the order matters: the value of the expression on the right is assigned to the variable on the left. So it should be:

```
Answer = int(Input1) * int(Input2)
```

The lefthand side of an assignment can't be a function call.

Answer (score 1):

```
Answer = 0
def Game():
    print('Hello! Enter in a number to multiply!')
    Input1 = input()
    print('Ok, now enter another number to multiply!')
    Input2 = input()
    print('Now let me think about that.....')
    Answer = int(Input1) * int(Input2)
    print('The answer to that is' + Answer + '!')

playAgain = 'yes'
while playAgain == 'yes':
    Game()
    print('Do you want to play again? (Yes or No?)')
    playAgain = input()
```